# Error in Python when dealing with lists read from a text file

Tags: python, list, split

Here is my code. I am newbie to Python:

```
    f=open('dt2.txt','r').read().split('\n')
    for i in range (len(f)):
        a=f[i].split('\t')
        print type(a)
        print str(a[1])," with roll no: ",str(a[0])," ",
        c=0
        d=0
        for j in range (0,100):
            try:
                if str(a[j])=="HU101":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU301":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU481":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU501":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU601":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU781":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU801A":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="HU801B":
                    c+=1
                if str(a[j])=="M101":
                    d+=1
            except IndexError:
                continue
    if c>d:
        print "is good in Soft Skills"
    else:
        print "is good in Quantitative & Logical Ability"
```

I am getting this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oArwx.png)

Comment: could you show us a sample of your `dt2.txt` ?

Comment: 1) Your code is not correctly indented. 2) You should post the error message, not a screenshot of it. 3) "As soon as possible"?

Comment: 12300110031.0  ABHIPSA KUNDU  HU181   XC181   CS291   ME291   CS391   CS392   CS393   M401   HU481   CS492   CS493   CS503   CS591   CS592   CS594B CS594D   CS691   CS692   CS681   
12300110071.0  ABHISHEK SINGH  HU181   XC181   CS391   CS392   CS493   CS592   CS593   CS681   HU781   CS792   CS891   CS892   ES191   CS291   PH291   ES291   ME291   CS393   HU481   MCS491   CS491   CS492   CS591   CS691   CS692   CS693
12300110049.0  ADITI BHAUMIK  XC181   ES291   CS392   CS393   HU481   CS491   CS492   CS493   CS592   CS593   CS691   CS692   CS693   CS681   CS795A   CS792   CS794   CS891

Comment: First off, don't do `open('filename.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')`, just do `open('filename.txt').readlines()`. And the error here is that it thinks that `f` is an integer.

Comment: @NickChapman: I tried using a=str(f[i]).split('\t'), but I am getting the same error

Comment: @SainikKrMahata it is complaining about the `f[i]` part.

Comment: @SiHa: I apologize for "As soon as possible"?

Comment: @NickChapman: Thanks, It solved my problem.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can help... In python the csv-library and with ... open is considered more "pythonic". The with ... open ensures the file is properly closed after being opened.

```
import csv
with open('dt2.txt') as f:
    mydata = [i for i in csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')] # one-liner
```

Another tip... you can also shorten your code dramatically by writing:

```
if str(a[j]) in ["HU101","HU301",...,"HU801B"]:
   c+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, this code is terrible. If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, this is a much cleaner way of doing the same:

```
f = open('dt2.txt','r') 
for line in f:
    a = line.split('\t')
    print "{} with roll no: {} ".format(a[1],a[0]),
    c = sum(1 for j in a if j in set("HU101", "HU301", "HU481", "HU501", "HU601", "HU781", "HU801A", "HU801B"))
    d = 1 if "M101" in a else 0
    if c>d:
        print "is good in Soft Skills"
    else:
        print "is good in Quantitative & Logical Ability"
f.close()
```